# Merge text file with existing table in power query

Tags: excel, csv, powerquery

I have an existing excel table with outstanding purchase orders and their status. Weekly I get a new text file with the current outstanding purchase orders.

I figured out how I can merge the existing comments to the new text file in power query, but I am struggling with how get it working so when the new list comes out I can just refresh. You can't have power query replace the existing table after the merge it only seems to be able to create a new table.

Left join of new to existing does what I want but creates new sheet, right of existing to new seem to create a lot of null fields.

Comment: I dont think you have provided enough information for us to help you. What do the files look like? What code are you using? How do you load the data from powerquery back into excel (table, pivot, etc).

Comment: Existing data is just a table that was loaded into excel. I used get data from table/range to load it into power query. The second file is a fixed with text file. The loading the merged/jointed file is where I am struggling. I can load to new table. But I just want to be able to hit refresh and merge the comments on purchase order status with the new list of outstanding purchase orders.

Comment: It is still unclear to me, but sounds like perhaps you want to preserve manually typed information upon refresh. If so, see https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/

Comment: Thank you. This looks promising hopefully I can take a detailed look today!